# Overlap between the training and testing set in cross validation settings

Tags: classification, sentiment-analysis

Why is it important to evaluate models using a cross-validation setting where the training and test sets have no overlap? I noticed that a violation of this guideline exaggerates the effectiveness of the models. But, I just do not understand how.

Answer (score 1):

Take the extreme case. Training data is the test data. You can use a model that is overfitting your training data (which is your test data). It is clear that your model will perform good on the test data, because it was trained on it.

By mixing training data and test data you are showing your model the test data, hence it can memorize it implicitly.

Our goal is to provide good generalization to real world data and the only way we have to check it is to test our model on unseen test data.